# I can't wrap my head aroung this python function for a sorted(key)

Tags: python

This returns a list of tuples sorted by the tuple's last character but I'm not sure why or how it works:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
  def last(a):
    return a[-1]
return sorted(tuples, key=last)
```

I don't understand why the two functions don't require shared arguments for this code to produce the desired result.

Can you explain how and or why this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` takes a `key` argument, which, from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

By passing the function `last` to `sorted`, it then calls `last(x)` for each `x` in `sorted`, and that return value used to determine the sort order. Had you passed an argument to `last`, such as `key=last(tuples)`, you wouldn't actually be passing the *function* to `sorted`, but rather passing the *return value* of a function. By omitting the `()`, the function itself is the argument.

Because your function returns `a[-1]`, that means it's sorting based on the last element of the tuple, without regard to any earlier elements.

Comment: I understand what a key is and what a[-1] represents.  I just don't understand how each tuple is passed through last(a).  a is not defined anywhere in the script.

Comment: You've passed `last` to `sorted`, which in turn is calling `last(x)` for each x in `tuples`

Comment: @HVAC-Dude You didn't read his answer very carefully, since it says it right smack in the middle. `sorted` calls `last(tuple)` for you.